# why does star unpacking in python give a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am curious on why python3's star unpacking returns me an instance of a list as compared to a tuple (which is returned by an asterisk in function argument). Is this a python's idiosyncrasy, or there is a good reason behind this.

```
In [1]: def foo(*args):
   ...:     print(type(args))
   ...:     

In [2]: foo(1, 2, 3, 4)
<class 'tuple'>

In [3]: first, *rest = (1, 2, 3, 4)

In [4]: type(rest)
Out[4]: list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[They figured a list would be easier to process:](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#acceptance)

> After a short discussion on the python-3000 list [[1]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#id3), the PEP
>   was accepted by Guido in its current form. Possible changes discussed
>   were:
>
> - ...
> - Make the starred target a tuple instead of a list. This would be consistent with a function's `*args`, but make further processing of
>     the result harder.

Comment: seems slightly random. Thanks for answering.